# Make my AS3 code go fetch information on a website that I don't own

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There is this website : http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ and I'd like to make my AS3 code go fetch some infos and displays it flash.

Is it possible if I don't own the website ?

Exemple : [image]

I want to display these infos in my AS3 code. Is this possible ? How can I do ?

Thx for your help,

---

EDIT

Thx to the full answer of VC.One I've managed to paste infos in a String.

Here's what I did :

```
var myString:String;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=plugin&a=Surfing&s=Anse%20Vata&country=nz&swellmap=1&country=ncd&swellmap=1&_=1460963404274"); 
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 

loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,weatherLoaded);


function weatherLoaded(e:Event):void{
myString = e.target.data;
    trace(myString);  //output is {"tides":"High: 05:40 am (1.32 m); Low: 12:10 pm (0.57 m); High: 06:10 pm (1.19 m); ","seatemp":"27&deg;C","forecastdate":"17h","rating":"<img src='http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/style\/img\/weathericons\/1r.png' alt='Poor conditions' title='Poor conditions' \/>","rating_class":"<span class='badge badge-important' alt='Poor conditions' title='Poor conditions'>1<\/span>","summary":"<img class='wx-summary' src='http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/style\/img\/weathericons\/suncloud.png'  title='Sunny with some cloud' \/>","title":"Anse Vata","smaplink":"http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/surfing\/new-caledonia\/anse-vata","vars":{"hs_sw":{"value":"0.4","title":"Swell","unit":"m"},"hs":{"value":"0.6","title":"Wave","unit":"m"},"wface":{"value":"0.8","title":"Set face","unit":"m"},"tp":{"value":"13","title":"Period","unit":"s"},"dpm":{"value":"S","title":"Swell dir","unit":"&#xb0;"},"windma":{"value":"E 12","title":"Wind","unit":"kts"},"gstma":{"value":"16","title":"Gusts","unit":"kts"}}}
}
```

Now, I didn't quite understand how could I retrieve only some infos (like the swell for exemple). 
Is it possible to show me in AS3 code, how could I do that ? (in this exemple, we can see that the swell is "0.4 m @ 13 s")

exemple of what I'd like to do :

```
function(searchTheSwell){
var swell_AnseVata;
swell_AnseVata =.... ?
info_txt.text = swell_AnseVata;
}
```

Comment: It's in JSON format. You have to parse it. After your string tracing, try `var myData : Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data); trace(myData);` does `myData` have any content? If so I'll update the answer...

Comment: the output for `trace(myData)` is `[object Object]`

Comment: :-) it seems that I've asked you a trick question ! :-) Do you think I should create a all the new question for this ?

Comment: Haha yes it is. Sorry for the delay.. just add this line to see the entries `for each (var s:* in myData) { trace("key:",s,"value:",myData[s]); }` .. now I just tried it and some things are missing. I dont usually use JSON.parse, I just do my own extract functions. I'll write an update for you soon.

Comment: :-) ok.super thx again

Comment: Check the edit if you still need the extraction code.

Comment: Perfect ! Thx again (god you"'re committed) ! You've been a HUGE help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Developer Tools of your browser then you'll see that there's a PHP file being accessed to get the information. It starts `http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=` and you need to find what it says for you. Now to view the contents just remove the part of the URL with `&callback=XYZ` where `XYZ` will be whatever the link has..

**1)**
Here's an example of how to get data for a location :

http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=plugin&a=Surfing&s=ZZZZZ&country=nz&swellmap=1&country=YYY&swellmap=1&_=1460950764514

Replace `&s=ZZZZZ` with name of location, so if I want `Anse Vata` it becomes `&s=Anse%20Vata` and `La Nera` becomes `&s=La%20Nera`. So use `%20` for any *spaces* in location name. Replace `&country=YYY` with example `&country=fra`.

**2)**
To get the JSON data for `Anse Vata`, declare your new String variable to later hold the JSON text and then just use URLStream in AS3 to load the link (open in browser tab to check contents) : 
 
 http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=plugin&a=Surfing&s=Anse%20Vata&country=nz&swellmap=1&country=ncd&swellmap=1&_=1460963404274

In the `Event Complete` listener function of URLStream you just use (example) `myString = e.target.data;`. Then use a JSON parser on your `myString` or do it manually yourself using String functions (like `indexOf` to word search).

**3)** If you opened the above **[link in an new tab](http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=plugin&a=Surfing&s=Anse%20Vata&country=nz&swellmap=1&country=ncd&swellmap=1&_=1460963404274)** you'll see the JSON entries you need to parse.

- Swell : `"hs_sw":{"value":"0.4","title":"Swell","unit":"m"}` and for
  extracting the `@ 13 s` period use :
  `"tp":{"value":"13","title":"Period","unit":"s"}`
- Wind : `"windma":{"value":"E 12","title":"Wind","unit":"kts"}`
- Icon : `"summary":"<img class='wx-summary'
  src='http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/style\/img\/weathericons\/suncloud.png'`

  You'll have to clean up the icon links so it becomes for example : 
  `http://www.swellmap.co.nz/style/img/weathericons/suncloud.png`

**EDIT** :

The code below extracts the expected information from the JSON string. Just replace `&s=` with any other location (eg: `&s=Ilot%20Tenia`) and it extracts the Swell, Wind and Icon URL entries...

```
var myURL : String = "http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=plugin&a=Surfing&s=Anse%20Vata&country=nz&swellmap=1&country=ncd&swellmap=1&_=1460963404274";

var URL_Req : URLRequest  = new URLRequest( myURL );
var URL_load:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

URL_load.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

try { URL_load.load( URL_Req ); } 
catch (error:Error) 
{ trace("Could not load - Please check URL is correct : " + error.message); }


var idx_start : int = 0;    var idx_end : int = 0;

var str_Swell : String = "";
var str_Swell_Period : String = "";
var str_Swell_Dir : String = "";
var str_Wind : String = "";     var url_Icon : String = "";


function completeHandler(e : Event):void 
{
    //var myData : Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data); 
    //for each (var s:* in myData) { trace("key:",s,"value:",myData[s]); }

    var myString : String = String(e.target.data);
    //trace ( "myString : " + myString);


    //# Get Swell
    idx_start = myString.indexOf("\"hs_sw\":" , 0 );
    idx_end = myString.indexOf("," , idx_start + 1 );
    str_Swell = myString.substring(idx_start + 18, idx_end-1);
    str_Swell = str_Swell + " m";
    //trace ("Swell : " + str_Swell );

    //# Get Direction (for Swell)
    idx_start = myString.indexOf("\"dpm\":" , 0 );
    idx_end = myString.indexOf("," , idx_start + 1 );
    str_Swell_Dir = myString.substring(idx_start + 16, idx_end-1);
    //trace ("Swell dir : " + str_Swell_Dir );

    //# Get time Period (for Swell)
    idx_start = myString.indexOf("\"tp\":" , 0 );
    idx_end = myString.indexOf("," , idx_start + 1 );
    str_Swell_Period = myString.substring(idx_start + 15, idx_end-1);
    str_Swell_Period = " @ " + str_Swell_Period + " s";
    //trace ("Period : " + string_Period );

    //# Join Swell Direction, Size & Period entries into one sentence
    str_Swell = str_Swell_Dir + " " + str_Swell + str_Swell_Period;
    trace ("Swell : " + str_Swell );

    //# Get Wind
    idx_start = myString.indexOf("\"windma\":" , 0 );
    idx_end = myString.indexOf("," , idx_start + 1 );
    str_Wind = myString.substring(idx_start + 19, idx_end-1);
    str_Wind = str_Wind + " kts";
    trace ("Wind :  " + str_Wind );

    //# get Image URL
    idx_start = myString.indexOf("\'wx-summary\'" , 0 );
    idx_end = myString.indexOf("'" , idx_start + 18 );
    url_Icon = myString.substring(idx_start + 18, idx_end);
    url_Icon = url_Icon.replace(/\\/g, "");

    trace ("URL : " + url_Icon );
    //# load image using : new URLRequest (url_Icon); 

}
```

Comment: Wawoo. that's a very detailled answer ! Super Thx ! (it's pretty rare to have an answer THAT detailled ! It's great !!!)

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Try something using above info and if you have any issues just update your Question including your code to fix. Or just ask another new question. You should be okay though. Thnx.

Comment: So I'll edit my post just now for a last question if you don't mind.