# How to take a specific info from a string in json format?

Tags: json, string, actionscript-3

I've got this AS3 code :

```
var myString:String;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.swellmap.co.nz/ajr.php?r=plugin&a=Surfing&s=Anse%20Vata&country=nz&swellmap=1&country=ncd&swellmap=1&_=1460963404274"); 
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 

loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,weatherLoaded);


function weatherLoaded(e:Event):void{
myString = e.target.data;
    trace(myString);  //output is {"tides":"High: 05:40 am (1.32 m); Low: 12:10 pm (0.57 m); High: 06:10 pm (1.19 m); ","seatemp":"27&deg;C","forecastdate":"17h","rating":"<img src='http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/style\/img\/weathericons\/1r.png' alt='Poor conditions' title='Poor conditions' \/>","rating_class":"<span class='badge badge-important' alt='Poor conditions' title='Poor conditions'>1<\/span>","summary":"<img class='wx-summary' src='http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/style\/img\/weathericons\/suncloud.png'  title='Sunny with some cloud' \/>","title":"Anse Vata","smaplink":"http:\/\/www.swellmap.co.nz\/surfing\/new-caledonia\/anse-vata","vars":{"hs_sw":{"value":"0.4","title":"Swell","unit":"m"},"hs":{"value":"0.6","title":"Wave","unit":"m"},"wface":{"value":"0.8","title":"Set face","unit":"m"},"tp":{"value":"13","title":"Period","unit":"s"},"dpm":{"value":"S","title":"Swell dir","unit":"&#xb0;"},"windma":{"value":"E 12","title":"Wind","unit":"kts"},"gstma":{"value":"16","title":"Gusts","unit":"kts"}}}
var myData : Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data); 
for each (var s:* in myData) { trace("key:",s,"value:",myData[s]); }
trace(myData);    }
```

My String is containing lots of infos. 
How could I take specifics informations ?

Exemple:
If I want to take the swell (in this example, the swell is : "0.4 m @ 13 s"). How could I do that? (the purpose is to displays it in a text box like that :

```
function(searchTheSwell){
var swell_AnseVata;
swell_AnseVata =.... ?
info_txt.text = swell_AnseVata;
}
```

Thx

Comment: If the JSON parsing doesn't work out, I've added **[some code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36686561/2057709)** example for extracting that info.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a breakpoint after you parse the data and examine the myData in the debugger - you will see the object structure. Or just trace the whole object structure out:

```
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(myData));
```

In your case you'd need to put your string together out of the vars in your object:

```
    var hs_sw:Object = myData.vars.hs_sw;
    var tp:Object = myData.vars.tp;

    trace(hs_sw.value + " " + hs_sw.unit + " @ " + tp.value + " " + tp.unit);
```

Comment: Where can I find mx.utils.ObjectUtil; ?

Comment: Oh right, it's only available in Flex, sorry. Here is a function to parse JSON objects: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/trace-print-json-object-in-as3